# One sample chi-square

Tags: chi-squared-test, cramers-v

I have analysed very data set using an online calculator. I used a chi-square comparing the differences between

- 'strongly agree/agree' 
        versus
- 'strongly disagree/disagree' to specific questions.

I only had 2 groups (or two sets of data)instead of the usual 4.

I now need to calculate the Cramers V in order to report the effect size in my results write up, but online calculators don't provide this tool. I now need to analyse the data using SPSS ticking the option to calculate the Cramer's V.

I am looking for advice as to how to I should lay my data out in SPSS. There is a lot of information online for when using 4 groups for observed frequencies, but nothing for 2 groups.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do.  Could you expand on this: Basically I used a chi-square comparing the differences between 'strongly agree/agree' versus 'strongly disagree/disagree'to specific questions..

Comment: Thanks Glen. I issued a questionnaire with a 5 point Likert scale. I am just comparing those who strongly agreed/agreed to those who strongly disagreed/disagreed for each question. I am using one one-sample chi-square for each answer.

Comment: I now need to calculate the effect size but realise that I need to perform the chi square in SPSS so that I can get the Cramer's V as online calculators don't provide this. I just need to know how to lay my data out in SPSS for the two groups.

Comment: Why was this question put on hold?  Sure it's not very clear, but it is clearly about statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're collapsing your 5 point Likert scale to two groups and throwing away the neutral response but with that aside, it seems you want to assess whether the proportion who selected SA/A is significantly different compared to the proportion that selected SD/D.  Since you only have two categories a Chi-Squared test doesn't make sense.  You can do a one sample proportion test for the SA/A (or vice versa) category and see if it is significantly different than 0.5.

For example, if out of 200 users (ignoring those who selected neutral) 120 selected SA/A then your estimated proportion is 0.6 and you can run a one sample proportion test.  There are effect sizes for proportions if you want to calculate those.

You seem pretty set on Cramer's V, probably because someone asked for it, but I don't see how it would apply here (which is probably why you're not finding a reference online).

I also have concerns analyzing your data this way but hope that helps.

Sample R code:

```
    library(vcd)
    library(powerAnalysis)
    set.seed(0807)
    # x vector represents your data, 0 could be SD/D and 1 A/SA
    # Note, these tests should all come back non significant
    x=sample(0:1,100,replace=TRUE)
    tab=table(x)
    print(tab)
    prop.table(tab)
    chisq.test(tab) 
    prop.test(tab)
    binom.test(tab)
    # effect size proportion 
    ES.proportions(p1 = prop.table(tab)[2], p2 = 0.5, alternative = c("two.sided",
                                                         "one.sided"))
    # does not work
    assocstats(tab)
```

Comment: That is extremely useful. I am collapsing the data because it is a small sample of 68 respondents. I was going to run the Cramer's V to test for effect size because of the small sample. I did a web search for the best effect size calculation for Chi-Squared tests and and the suggestion was Cramer's V or Phi, but Cramer's V seemed to be the preferred. Initially I was just going to analyse the data using a a Mann-Whitney, but I was advised to use a Chi-Squared.

Comment: Would you say that a Chi-Square is completely inapproriate for this articular analysis, or just not the best test to use?!

Comment: A chi-squared test will work fine whenever a t-test or Normal approximation to the Binomial test of proportions will work--it's practically equivalent to either one.  With smallish datasets, where those approximations might break down, you should be using the Binomial test or its equivalent.

Comment: So what would the formula be to calculate Cramer's V or Phi for a Chi-Square with just 2 groups?

Comment: @Maggie2018 I've added R code to compute some of these tests in R.  I've included the cohen's d effect size for proportion.  The associated stats does not work for this table, which would have computed Cramer's V.  I'm not sure how to do it for two categories.  Of all these tests, I would recommend binom.test as whuber suggests, but they should all be relative similar (smaller sample size will exhibit greater differences however).  Not sure why people are putting your question on hold, that's a shame.

Comment: I wasn't sure myself either! I'm new on here so I'm not completely confident how it all works but have made a few edits, so hopefully they will open the question up again soon. I am not familiar with R, I use SPSS. In your opinion would you say that I am okay using a Chi-Square? - Even though a binom.test would be better. Or would you recommend starting over again ? Thank you so much for your advice on here and the trouble you went to adding the R code.

Comment: As @whuber suggests, roughly speaking, if the sample size is less than 30 then I would use a binomial test and not trust the chi-squared.  If your sample size is above 30 then either one is fine, but if you can stick with the binomial might as well use it as it is not an approximation.  The proportion test can easily give you an effect size.  All three tests should be relatively consistent, especially as your n increases.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and thank you to @whuber too. I really do appreciate your advice and your time.

Comment: I have analysed my 2 x 1 Chi-Squares in SPSS now, but there was no option to calculate an effect size. I now understand why I can't use Cramer's V for a 2 x 1 contingency table. So can I now just go a head and use a proportion test to find the effects size and report this after my Chi-Square?

Comment: I think you can calculate the effect size directly from the Chi-Square test as sqrt(Chi-Squared/N).  See here: https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Chi-Square_Effect_Size_Calculator.pdf

Comment: Would the formula still be the same even though it's a 2 x 1 Chi-Square?

Comment: Would the formula still be the same even though it's a 2 x 1 Chi-Square?

Comment: Yes.  Also as a side note, since you're probably running many tests, you should be you may consider doing some sort of multiple testing adjustment.  http://www.biostathandbook.com/multiplecomparisons.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have done 11 chi-square tests - is that enough to consider a multiple testing adjustment?

Comment: There are no hard rules.  I don't know without being involved in the analysis.  You should at least be aware of the issue.

Comment: The link that you sent to the chi-square effect size was really useful and I have used the Cohen's w formula - sqrt(chi-squared/n). This looks the same as the formula for Phi. Would you happen to know the difference between Phi and the calculation for Cohen's w?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer by @Glen .

I think there's a little confusion in the subsequent discussion with the term "chi-square test".

Cramér's *V* is usually used in cases of a chi-square test of association (or test of independence).  In this case, each side of the contingency test needs to have a least two categories.  That is, the table is at least 2 x 2 in size.

The question asks about a situation for which a chi-square goodness-of-fit test is applicable.  Here, the contingency table is 1 x k.  As indicated by @Glen, an effective way to express the effect size in this case is simply to present the proportions.  In the case of a 1 x 2 table, this makes complete sense, and is easily interpreted by the audience.

There is a variant of Cramér's *V* that could be used in the case of the chi-square goodness-of-fit test.  Cramér's *V* in the usual case is `sqrt(Chi.sq/N/min(R - 1, C - 1))`, where *Chi.sq* is the chi-square statistic, *N* is the total number of observations, *R* is the number of categories in rows, and *C* is the number of categories in columns.  By analogy, in the case of chi-square goodness of fit, a statistic can be calculated as `sqrt(Chi.sq/N/(K - 1))`, where *K* is the number of categories.

Unfortunately, I don't have any good reference for this modified statistic except for the [R function I wrote](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rcompanion/versions/2.0.3/topics/cramerVFit).  There is also a [function in the lsr package that works in this case](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lsr/versions/0.5/topics/cramersV).  I note [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_03.html) that if the theoretical proportions for the categories are equal, that Cramér's *V* for goodness-of-fit tests will range from 0 to 1.  If theoretical proportions are not equal, Cramér's *V* can exceed 1.

```
### Code for R:

observed = c(10, 20, 30, 40)

library(rcompanion)
cramerVFit(observed)

   ### Cramer V 
   ###  0.2582

library(lsr)
cramersV(observed)

   ### [1] 0.2581989
```